# Android L GMail app remove default account

Tags: sync, gmail, 5.0-lollipop

I currently have Android L (5.0.1) installed on my Nexus 5. I thought my phone had a problem with syncing but it turns out that my GMail app keeps trying to sync my email address with GMail. I have an @live.nl email and this email is the same email as I use for my Google account.

So, the GMail app tries to get my @live.nl email from GMail's servers, but since this is a @live.nl email and not GMail, it keeps saying "trying to sync". I have no way of deleting this account without deleting my entire Google account from my device, something I do not want because it stores all my data. I can also not add my @live.nl email because it keeps saying it's a duplicate. It seems like I'm stuck in a loophole.

Does anyone know if there's a way to make the GMail app not try to retrieve my email from the GMail servers? I already unticked "Sync with GMail", but it keeps trying anyway.

Comment: The GMail app on Android L (5.0.1 at least) allows you to add GMail, Yahoo, Outlook and also Exchange accounts. http://www.cnet.com/how-to/get-gmail-5-0-for-android-right-now/

Comment: So when you first added this account you selected Outlook and not GMail correct?

Comment: I updated my phone from Android 4.4.4 to Android 5.0 and once I launched the default Email app it gave me a notification that my accounts have been merged to the GMail app. I did not have the GMail app enabled at that point. I already had my Outlook account working and I had another IMAP email set up. Both worked fine, up until now.

Comment: I would create an alias for your `@live.nl` then use that to login into your `@live.nl` account.  That won't solve your syncing problems with your current account though.

Comment: That will still keep my GMail app trying to sync my GMail email I don't have. It pops up every time I open the app and disabling syncing everywhere won't make it go away.

Comment: Sounds like you should wipe the device and reconfigure it under 5.0 the upgrade you did was pretty major.

Comment: The upgrade is just one step up. I do not want to wipe the device as I do not want to lose all my information on my phone. It's not just photos, also a lot of apps that have their own data and such that is not synced between devices.